# addEventListener on a body element does not get executed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ie11-developer-tools

I am using MS Edge in IE11 compatibility mode and have an `HTML` page in which I have:

```
<input id="onLoadAttributeHiddenId" type="hidden" value="schadenAuswahl.setCustomCheck();schadenAuswahl.createArrays();">
```

Further below, I have also:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1" src="../js/table_head_uip.js"></script>
```

And in the `table_head_uip.js`, I have:

document.body.addEventListener('load', customOnLoadFunction, false);

```
function customOnLoadFunction(){
    var onLoadAttributeFunctStr = document.getElementById("onLoadAttributeHiddenId").value;

    var onLoadAttributeFunct = new Function(onLoadAttributeFunctStr);
    onLoadAttributeFunct; 
}
```

Now, when I put breakpoints in the `table_head_uip.js`, the line.

```
   var onLoadFunct = document.body.addEventListener('load', customOnLoadFunction, false);
```

It gets executed, but the function `customOnLoadFunction` never gets completed. Also, I do not receive any errors in the console.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `.addEventListener()` always returns `undefined`. Also, in `customOnLoadFunction()`, you don't call that function you construct; it needs `()` after the reference to be a function call.

Comment: Also there's no need for the `language` attribute.

Comment: I am  sorry, I did not get your second point. But I corrected my question, so that hopefully your first point should be now OK. Could you please elaborate on what exactly did you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` events only fire on elements which load things (like an `<img>` with a `src` attribute) and the `window` object (for when the entire document, including its dependencies, has loaded).

The body element doesn't load anything.

The equivalent of the obsolete `onload` attribute for the body is a load event that fires on the `window` object. That attribute only existed because, since `window` isn't an element, you couldn't put attributes on it.

---

Additionally, the statement `onLoadAttributeFunct` doesn't do anything. To be useful you need to, for example, put `()` after it to call it.

`new Function(onLoadAttributeFunctStr)` is effectively a time delayed `eval` and is considered dangerous, slow, and hard to debug. You should reconsider the design of your application if you need that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and especially for "the statement onLoadAttributeFunct doesn't do anything"